# How to hide youtube logo in youtube player in android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I don't want to share youtube videos in my android application.But when i click youtube logo in youtube playe, the link goes to youtube website.

So, How can i hide youtube logo in youtube player.Please suggest some ideas...

Think is i don't want to share youtube videos

Comment: It's not a good idea to do that. [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms) said that you can not "modify, replace or otherwise disable the functioning of links to YouTube or third-party websites provided in the YouTube search results or otherwise provided through the YouTube API or YouTube player."

Comment: But if you still need to, cover the youtube player with a view and view.setEnabled(false);

Comment: Which style are you using for youtubeplayerview?

Comment: I am using default style

Comment: Ok see my answer below, it may help you

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what kind of style you want, but you can use YouTube Player as Activity or Fragment or a View. So you can basically customise your player easily with new YouTubePlayer API. If you want some simple youtube player with fullscreen (no titlebar mode).

You can pick he chromeless style, it doesn't have any controls - it's only a rectangle that plays a video under programmatic control. 
You're free to implement your own controls UI outside the player and wire them up through the YouTubePlayer that you get back after initializing a YouTubePlayerView or YouTubePlayerFragment. Keep in mind that, as mentioned in the YouTubePlayerView JavaDoc, "it is not permitted to overlay the [player] view with other views while a video is playing"

Refer below links:

1] https://gist.github.com/TheFinestArtist/5545437

2]https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle#Enums

Comment: @Arun kumar Why you accepted my answer & then unaccepted it

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
ViewGroup tmpVg = youTubeView;

int[] loopLv = new int[]{0,0,4,0,0,3,0,1};

for( int i = 0; i < loopLv.length; i++){
    if( i == loopLv.length-1 ){
        tmpVg.getChildAt(loopLv[i]).setVisibility( View.GONE );
    } else {
        tmpVg = (ViewGroup)tmpVg.getChildAt( loopLv[i] );
    }
}
```

your problem will be solved.

Comment: what is your android version?

Comment: 5.0.1 verison. I soved my problem using chromeless style. but why it's not working?

Comment: Thanks, worked fine for me on Nougat, still need to test it on other releases and devices.