# Removing elements from within the YouTubePlayerView in Android

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

My YouTube video shows an overflow menu, full screen, open in YouTube buttons from within the `YouTubePlayerView` or the `YouTubePlayerFragment`.

Is there any way to remove those items? I can't find anything in the docs.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked out this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707731/how-to-hide-youtube-logo-in-youtube-player-in-android)? It mentioned this [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle#Enums)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the **style** `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS` in initialization to completely remove all available controls.

In `onInitializationSuccess` add `ytPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);`.

Check [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle) for more details.

**Edit :** You can add your own controls using either a DialogFragment or Dialog on top of the YoutubePlayer. This will allow you to control playback completely using your own buttons and seekbar. And it does the trick of removing Youtube App Button from player.

Comment: But this PlayerStyle will not allow you to control seekbar also.

Comment: No but you can add your own controls using DialogFragment on top of the `YoutubePlayer`. This will allow you to control playback completely using your own buttons and seekbar. An it does the trick of removing Youtube App Button from player. Also if you don't want to do everything yourself, you can replace `ytPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS);` with `ytPlayer.setPlayerStyle(YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.MINIMAL);` it will let you keep next/prev/play/pause but you will still have to make your own SeekBar.

Comment: MINIMAL has only Play&Pause button @Abbas

Comment: @ArnoldBrown a link is already provided which lists all the available `YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle`s.

Answer (score 3):

Yes You can disable full screen from default player,You need to just use below code with your player object.

```
//To disable full screen mode.
player.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
```

Use above line to hide full screen button from your default youtube player.Hope this will work for you.