# How can I remove "To youtube" button in youtube player?

Tags: android, youtube

I am developing an Android app in order to play "unlisted" videos. If the button "To youtube" is there, people will see the URL and therefore videos won´t be "unlisted". Consequently, i want to remove this button.

[image]

Could you say me the way to do this? Do i need to create a custom player with an open youtube library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing elements from within the YouTubePlayerView in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980341/removing-elements-from-within-the-youtubeplayerview-in-android)

Comment: Modest branding solves some of this. YouTube logo only displays when the video is paused or on mouse-hover. [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#modestbranding)